# Junit test from commandline No runnable method exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

TestJunit class

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
public class TestJunit 
{
   @Test
   public void testAdd() 
   {
      String str= "Junit is working fine";
      assertEquals("Junit is working fine",str);
   }
}

TestRunner class
/********************************************/
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

I used

```
javac -cp /root/Documents/unit\ tests/junit-4.10.jar TestJunit.java TestRunner.java
```

to compile and

```
java -cp /root/Documents/unit\ tests/junit-4.10.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestRunner
```

to run.
It compiles without errors but the tests fail with an exception. My test methods are annotated with `@Test`. Why do I get this error?

Comment: When running I must mention TestJunit, not TestRunner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that exception when the class that you passed in the command line arguments doesn't have any methods annotated with `@Test`. In this case, `TestRunner` doesn't have any methods annotated with `@Test`.

To run your unit tests, do:

```
java -cp /root/Documents/unit\ tests/junit-4.10.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestJunit
```

or alternatively:

```
java -cp /root/Documents/unit\ tests/junit-4.10.jar:. TestRunner
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the test class worked fine from IDE but it didn't work from a commandline.

I only got it to work when I added a "Test" postfix to the test class name.

I was using JUnit 4.12.